# Change background color of Colorbox using JS, based on Node ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I have a Drupal site which uses Views to show a list of nodes, which when clicked, is shown in a Colorbox.

Now, I'm trying to change the background color of this Colorbox, and it should be different depending on which node the user clicked on.

I'm trying to follow this example: http://jsfiddle.net/UFtrK/112/ ;
**but I just can't get it to work - the bg color doesn't change - ever.**
What am I doing wrong?

Here's an link example:

```
<a class="colorbox-node colorbox-color init-colorbox-node-processed-processed" href="/node/55?width=800&height=550" data-bg="#0E83CD">freaky mash up</a>
```

This is my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".colorbox-color").colorbox({
    onComplete: function(){
        var bg = $.colorbox.element().data('bg');
        $('#cboxWrapper').css('backgroundColor', bg);
        $('#cboxLoadedContent').css('backgroundColor', bg);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: on what browser do you get this issue? it works on chrome

Comment: Works on Chrome. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nevster/YSgMx/).

Comment: Works neither in Firefox, nor CHromium. Both latest.
Maybe it is something wrong with my Drupal theme, then..?

Comment: How are you building the colorbox link inside Views? Are you sure it is printed in HTML the way you write it here?